# Изменить значение select при изменении другого select

Tags: javascript, html-form

У меня есть два фильтра по категориям зачислений и расходов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу, чтобы при изменении опции у правого фильтра у левого фильтра менялся selected на первую опцию и делался submit формы. И чтобы это работало и в обратном порядке.

Как это сделать?

**Мой код:**

```html
<form id="form_filter_history" method="POST">
  <select name="month_filter_history" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option disabled>Период</option>
    <option value="1">Ноябрь 2020</option>
    <option value="2">Октябрь 2020</option>
    <option value="3">Сентябрь 2020</option>
  </select>

  <select name="income_filter_history" id="income_select" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="" disabled>Категории зачислений</option>
    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  </select>

  <select name="expense_filter_history" id="expense_select" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="" disabled>Категории расходов</option>
    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сделал две функции

```
function change_selected_income_option()
{
    document.getElementById('income_select').value="";
    let form = document.getElementById('form_filter_history');
    form.submit();
}

function change_selected_expense_option()
{
    document.getElementById('expense_select').value="";
    let form = document.getElementById('form_filter_history');
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: Если мой ответ выше Вам помог, просьба поставить галочку и проголосовать

Answer (score 1):

```js
let form = document.querySelector('form')
let filterByIncome = form.income_filter_history
let filterByExpense = form.expense_filter_history

filterByIncome.addEventListener('change', () => {
  let defaultOption = [...filterByExpense.options].findIndex(option => option.getAttribute('value', '1'))
  filterByExpense.selectedIndex = defaultOption
  form.submit()
})

filterByExpense.addEventListener('change', () => {
  let defaultOption = [...filterByIncome.options].findIndex(option => option.getAttribute('value', '1'))
  filterByIncome.selectedIndex = defaultOption
  form.submit()
})
```

```html
<form method="POST">
  <select name="month_filter_history">
    <option disabled>Период</option>
    <option value="1">Ноябрь 2020</option>
    <option value="2">Октябрь 2020</option>
    <option value="3">Сентябрь 2020</option>
  </select>

  <select name="income_filter_history" id="income_select">
    <option disabled>Категории зачислений</option>
    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  </select>

  <select name="expense_filter_history" id="expense_select">
    <option disabled>Категории расходов</option>
    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```